# Search page does not show the search results in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I have a searchform.php file which contains the following code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsumit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

Also in my index.php I've inserted this code:

```
<div class="search">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

**Now When I search for something I get no results.** Therefore I added a search.php file to show the results in it but I still don't get the results. What kind of changes should be made? Or what piece of code is lacking?

Note that I want to show the results in a separate page which must be search.php in Wordpress.

Comment: Did you try Wordpress' default search form? That way you don't need to add searchform.php.

Comment: @parisa Yes I did. But no results were shown. I also tried the HTML5 format of search for with adding `add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );` to my functions.php file and again no results were shown. 

Answer (score 3):

You need to add search.php file inside the theme and in that you will need to add the view for the search result page and the result can be obtained by looping for e.g

```
 while(have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
//here is your data
endwhile;
```